# Spring security Oauth and SSO

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, single-sign-on, oauth-2.0

Can anyone Tell me if it is possible to combine SSO from Spnego and Spring security with Oauth

This is my problem : 
The Client I now represent has chosen Spnego as their SSO solution.
This requires us to use a full blown appServer (Liberty) in all scenarios.
At the same time, the knowlegde and skills about Spnego in the developent team is very limited.

Due to issues with creating the keytab files, Spnego is only available in the formal test environment and not our local test enviroment.
This makes it very difficult/time consuming to test and devlop due to the long deployment time to the formal test enviroment.
Not over to my question:

If possible I would like to be able to "log in" to a service in the formal test enviroment (OAUTH2 authentication server ?) using SPNEGO SSO and get a token back that I can use in further requests towards my services located locally and/or in any other test enviroment.
Is this even possible ? I have not seen any examples where the authenticantionServer is using another sso provider to actually authenticate the user.

A different possibility might be to to do some sort of redirect from the login service in the test environment but I fear the Spnego token created only will be valid on a sever in the same domain..

I`m sorry if this question is confusing or not clear.
My knowledge of this domain (security) is limited and I struggle to get a grasp of how I can test my code locally with security enabled.

Links to any resources on the net that addresses some of these issues will be greatly appreciated.